# How to conditionally skip a unit test in Android and kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to run a unit test based on whether this asset exists at runtime. The reason is, I am downloading the file in react native and in android, I am running some unit tests that requires this file.

I would like to run the unit test only if this file exists. Does anyone have any suggestions or code samples on how this can be achieved? Or is there another way these unit tests can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do that in a unit test because you want to have the file locally in your testing environment or have a mock that provides it. Otherwise you're not [Eradicating Non-Determinism in Tests](https://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html).

Let's assume you need to do something like that anyway. So, I would add a condition in the assert expression:

```
@Test
fun `Given a variable When has a value Then assert it has a value`(){
      
  var myVar = null
  myVar = getAValue()
  myVar?.let {
    assertNotEquals(null, myVar)
  }
}
```

To me, eradicating non determinism in this particular context means that test scope has always specific expected values, the conditional expression in the let or an if enclosing an assert expression violates that. Hence the code above shouldn't be part of your tests. Instead, you have to write a test for the case myVar is null, you write another test for the case myVar is non null.

That's why I use [Given, When, Then](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/GivenWhenThen.html) the conditional state would make the Given/When very messy.

Comment: So to follow the "eradicating non-determinism in tests", should I just not create these unit tests? Just wondering what is the best practice.

Comment: You should eradicate non-determinism in your tests :). I don't know the specifics of your source but making some assumptions, I believe it may make sense to check in a test if a variable has a value or not but what you shouldn't be doing is get that value from a third party service. You mock the service, so when you run the test the service has a value or not. Check the idea behind mockito and MockWebserver works or why and what do we use them for.